# Issue in adding time to array of date

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to add hour and minutes to array of dates following is my code and i have put NSLog of old array and after array

```
 NSDate* date= _timePicker.date;
    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];


    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter1=[[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
    [formatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd:MM:yyyy"];


    [formatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    [formatter1 setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];


    NSDateFormatter *formatter3=[[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
    [formatter3 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm"];

    [formatter3 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    [formatter3 setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

    NSString *timeselected =[formatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSLog(@"we have picked time %@",timeselected);


    NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:timeselected];

    // NSLog(@"date2%@",dateSelected );

       NSLog(@"old%@",delegate.notificationBirthDateArray);
old(
    "15/08/2013",
    "15/07/2014",
    "15/07/2014",
    "07/06/2014",
    "15/01/2014",
    "27/01/2014",
    "20/01/2014",
    "22/06/2014",
    "29/08/2013",
    "15/06/2014",
    "16/07/2013"
)


    for (int i=0; i<[delegate.notificationBirthDateArray count]; i++) {



        NSDate *date1 = [formatter1 dateFromString:[delegate.notificationBirthDateArray objectAtIndex:i]];
     //   NSLog(@"date2%@",date2);
     //   NSLog(@"array%@",date1);

        NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

        // Extract date components into components1
        NSDateComponents *components1 = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit
                                                             fromDate:date1];

        // Extract time components into components2
        NSDateComponents *components2 = [gregorianCalendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:date2];

        // Combine date and time into components3
        NSDateComponents *components3 = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

        [components3 setYear:components1.year];
        [components3 setMonth:components1.month];
        [components3 setDay:components1.day];

        [components3 setHour:components2.hour];
        [components3 setMinute:components2.minute];
        // when i nslog this components they are printed perfectly

        // Generate a new NSDate from components3.
        NSDate *combinedDate = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:components3];   

        // combinedDate contains both your date and time!

          NSString *lastdate =[formatter3 stringFromDate:combinedDate];

       NSLog(@"combinedDate%@",lastdate);



        [delegate.notificationBirthDateArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        [delegate.notificationBirthDateArray insertObject:lastdate atIndex:i];



    }
 NSLog(@"new%@",delegate.notificationBirthDateArray);
new(
    "6:00:00 PM GMT+05:30",
    "6:00:00 PM GMT+05:30",
    "6:00:00 PM GMT+05:30",
    "6:00:00 PM GMT+05:30",
    "6:00:00 PM GMT+05:30",
    "6:00:00 PM GMT+05:30",
    "6:00:00 PM GMT+05:30",
    "6:00:00 PM GMT+05:30",
    "6:00:00 PM GMT+05:30",
    "6:00:00 PM GMT+05:30",
    "6:00:00 PM GMT+05:30"
)
```

Issue is time which is obtained gets added in correct way which you see above, but where is my dates gone? they should be there too.

Please help me with this.

```
edited and imporved code but still same problem

    NSArray*arr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:delegate.notificationBirthDateArray];


    NSDate* date= _timePicker.date;
    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];


    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter1=[[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
    [formatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];



    NSDateFormatter *formatter3=[[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
    [formatter3 setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"];

    [formatter3 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    [formatter3 setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

    NSString *timeselected =[formatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSLog(@"we have picked time %@",timeselected);


    NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:timeselected];

    // NSLog(@"date2%@",dateSelected );

       NSLog(@"old%@",delegate.notificationBirthDateArray);


   for (int i=0; i<arr.count; i++)  {

       NSString *datefromarray = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[delegate.notificationBirthDateArray objectAtIndex:i]];


        NSDate *date1 = [formatter1 dateFromString:datefromarray];
   // NSLog(@"hour time %@",[delegate.notificationBirthDateArray objectAtIndex:i]);
       NSLog(@"hour time %@",date2);
        NSLog(@"date%@",date1);

        NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

        // Extract date components into components1
        NSDateComponents *components1 = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit
                                                             fromDate:date1];

        // Extract time components into components2
        NSDateComponents *components2 = [gregorianCalendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:date2];

        // Combine date and time into components3
        NSDateComponents *components3 = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

        [components3 setYear:components1.year];
        [components3 setMonth:components1.month];
        [components3 setDay:components1.day];

        [components3 setHour:components2.hour];
        [components3 setMinute:components2.minute];


        // Generate a new NSDate from components3.
        NSDate *combinedDate = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:components3];   

        // combinedDate contains both your date and time!

          NSString *lastdate =[formatter3 stringFromDate:combinedDate];

       NSLog(@"combinedDate%@",lastdate);



        [delegate.notificationBirthDateArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        [delegate.notificationBirthDateArray insertObject:lastdate atIndex:i];



    }
 NSLog(@"new%@",delegate.notificationBirthDateArray);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see one issue here :

```
for (int i=0; i<[delegate.notificationBirthDateArray count]; i++) {
     //Your code
     [delegate.notificationBirthDateArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];                    
     [delegate.notificationBirthDateArray insertObject:lastdate atIndex:i];
}
```

You shouldn't use the `notificationBirthDateArray` in the for loop and do actions on it , it will bring unexpected problems,so i recommend on using another array as a placeholder in the for loop.

```
NSArray*arr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:delegate.notificationBirthDateArray];
```

then if you want do this:

```
for (int i=0; i<arr.count; i++) 
    {
         //Your code
         [delegate.notificationBirthDateArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];                    
         [delegate.notificationBirthDateArray insertObject:lastdate atIndex:i];
    }
```

Could be more things here, but i think you should modify like i mentioned and post the new outcome.

Remove from the formatter1 the line :

```
[formatter1 setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
```

and modify the line :

```
 [formatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd:MM:yyyy"];
```

to :

```
[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
```

If your string dates are exactly like in the old array;

Comment: hi @soryngod if array is `NSMutableArray` what problems may occur? Pls can you tell me ?

Comment: @preetam you could for example encounter an exception that the array was mutated while being enumerated.

Comment: @soryngod same output as before only time no dates ew(
    "6:28:00 PM GMT+05:30",
    "6:28:00 PM GMT+05:30",
    "6:28:00 PM GMT+05:30",
    "6:28:00 PM GMT+05:30",
    "6:28:00 PM GMT+05:30",
    "6:28:00 PM GMT+05:30",
    "6:28:00 PM GMT+05:30",
    "6:28:00 PM GMT+05:30",
    "6:28:00 PM GMT+05:30",
    "6:28:00 PM GMT+05:30",
    "6:28:00 PM GMT+05:30"
)

Comment: i did nslog date1 is showing null why this is happning is my formater is wrong ?

Comment: I think yes, your formatted might be wrong, i'll check it now

Comment: i solved that null thing but still same problem i think something is wrong with my formater

Comment: Modify it like this :NSDateFormatter *formatter1=[[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
    [formatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    
    
    [formatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

Comment: Remove from formatter1 the line : [formatter1 setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

Comment: i already removed it but not working but let me try that new code which you given me

Comment: I succesfully converted the date like that, you mean you get the same final array or the date1 is null ?

Comment: nothing is null now but the problem is in last i get only time dates are not there

Comment: @preetam problems may occur when you play with future indexes and modify those values.

Comment: Have you logged the components.month,.year,.day to see what you are getting there?

Comment: no let me see but i believe it should be there let me see ill tell you

Comment: i don't think it will do something but try adding seconds too,and the combinedData is coming out without year,month and day?.

Comment: i added seconds but still same problem :((((((

Comment: i saw that you nslogged  NSLog(@"combinedDate%@",lastdate); and not the actual NSDate *combinedDate , log that and if the date shows corectly then your formatter is wrong

Comment: so the combined date is correct and the formatter is only showing the hours and minutes?

Comment: sorry sir the time was over thats why i wasnt able to communicate  with you. yes it means my formater3 is wrong as you said

Answer (score 0):

To add an hours/minutes time interval to an NSDate, use `dateWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:`.

```
NSDate* oldDate = <some date>;
NSTimeInterval timeToAdd = ((hoursToAdd * 60) + minutesToAdd) * 60.0;
NSDate* newDate = [theDate dateWithTimeInterval:timeToAdd sinceDate:oldDate];
```

You could also do it with NSDateComponents, or by formatting the date, manipulating the characters, and scanning it back to NSDate, but both take dozens of lines and are fraught with chances for error.

(However, if you are starting with a character date, and you just want to add a "boiler plate" time value, just concatenate the pieces together and scan the result:

```
NSString* oldDate = @"22/06/14";
NSString* dateWithTime = [oldDate appendString:@" 6:00:00 PM GMT+05:30"];
NSDateFormatter* df = [NSDateFormatter new];
df.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yy h:mm:ss A 'GMT'ZZZZZ";  (or something like that)
NSDate* scannedDate = [df dateFromString:dateWithTime];
```

(Or, if you don't need the NSDate, skip the date formatter entirely.)